# app.relaunch failing, cant relaunch the electron app after errors

Tags: node.js, electron

I am relaunching my app with

```js
app.relaunch()
app.quit()
```

Yet I get the error `electron LaunchProcess failed`. Maybe it is because I am doing operations that time? I am running a loop that send requests, as they are not over?

I tried to do a batch script like this

```cmd
:a
electron relaunch.js
goto a
```

Yet it seems the program just quits and stops. What could be the problem? Are there alternative ways?

If i do `process.exit(0)` isn't the batch file supposed to keep working?

As an example, to my understanding this snippet is supposed to keep printing `hi` yet it stops after first.

```js
app.whenReady().then( async () => {
    console.log("hi");
    app.relaunch();
})
```